# add mouseListener to an array of JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

i have an 2D array with JPanels and i want to add a mouseListener in every JPanel in the array so i use 2 for loops to add them ,but i want to pass the variables i used in for loops in every mouseListener but when i try to do that all mouseListener have the same value of the last variables used in the last for loops .so what am i doing wrong ?

here is my code :

```
 for (i=0 ; i<3; i++) {
    for (k=0; k<3; k++) {
       a[i][k].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                  temp = a[i-1][k];
                  a[i-1][k] = a[i][k];
                  a[i][k] = temp;
                  //some
                  //code here 
            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
                {
                    invalidate();
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) 
                {}
            public void mouseExited  (MouseEvent e) {

                }


            });

        }
    }
```

I just need to know if there is a way to pass to mouselisteners the variables i,k as arguments to the mouseListener

Comment: a[i-1][k] = a[i][k]; with a loop starting in i=0???

Comment: Store the variables into temporaries... should probably work.

Comment: saving something in array[-1] is never a good idea..

Comment: Good catch @AsierAranbarri.. check array bounds as well

Comment: yeah but it is some sample code,i have a bigger problem at the moment

Comment: that would give you a great outOfBoundsException.

Comment: yeah i know that thank you

Comment: I recommend separating the listener to a different class.

Comment: and how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Okay, just saying, just want to help. ; )

Comment: is it a way to create an aray of mouselisteners get arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass `final` local variables and class fields into anonymous methods.

I recommend creating a new class that implements `MouseAdapter` that takes the array and the appropriate indices as arguments in the constructor. Then you can save them as fields in the class and use them when the `MouseEvent`s are called.

If you need to access additional variables that you haven't mentioned here, you can always pass them into this new class's constructor.

### Code:

```
public AppletMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
  private final JApplet theApplet;
  private final Container[][] a;
  private final int i;
  private final int j;

  public AppletMouseListener(JApplet theApplet, Container[][] a, int i, int k) {
    this.theApplet = theApplet;
    this.a = a;
    this.i = i;
    this.k = k;
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    JComponent temp = a[i-1][k];
    a[i-1][k] = a[i][k];
    a[i][k] = temp;
    //some
    //code here 
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    theApplet.invalidate();
    theApplet.revalidate();
    theApplet.repaint();
  }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use a constructor to save the variables within the mouseListener?

Comment: If you make the listener a class, you would use that class's constructor to create an object of that listener. You can then pass this object to addMouseListener.

Comment: if i create a new class that implements MouseAdapter is there a way this class to have access to the JApplet that it has the variables that i put as arguments to the class that implements MouseAdapter? i ask you because when i try to do that it gives an error that non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: but i need to call the invalidate and revalidate methods of the JApplet and also the add method for the JApplet,i cant pass them as arguments ,how can i do that?

Comment: Pass the `JApplet` itself into the constructor

Comment: i know how to save it in the new class but what i dont know is how can i pass it as argument for example in the applet i use the addMouseListener(AppletMouseListener(____,a_in,ii,jj)); ,so what i need to know is what to put as the first argument...and i also want to mention that i used this as the first argument but it didnt worked because i use the addMouseListener in a ActionListener inside the applet for another reason and i cant call the MouseListener outside the actionlistener

Comment: Put the `this` keyword, and use `new MouseListener` in the `for` loop

Comment: i use this keyword but it gives me an error that tells me that i try to pass an unknown ActionListener instead of an JApplet because i use addMouseListener within an ActionListener

Comment: Pass the applet as an argument to the ActionListener

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be clearer if you use a normal (named) class instead of an anonymous one. Then you can pass the relevant things (`a`, `i`, and `k`) to the constructor.

Anonymous classes can't have constructors but they can access local variables declared `final`.

```
for (int ii=0 ; ii<3; ii++) {
    for (int kk=0; kk<3; kk++) {
        final int i = ii;
        final int k = kk;
        a[i][k].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                JPanel temp = a[i-1][k]; // index out of bounds
                a[i-1][k] = a[i][k];
                a[i][k] = temp;
            }
            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                invalidate();
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
            public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseExited  (MouseEvent e) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this works but gosh it's confusing and [smells bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Comment: @durron597 I'll move the named class suggestion to the top, but I still think it's important to show how this could be done using anonymous classes.